# How to properly structure an event handling Application?

Tags: c++, oop

I need to write an application using C++ which handles input signal from various sources and end up with something like this:

- InputManager: handle input signals and convert them to messages.
- Processor: it will receive all messages from the input. Put it in a
  queue and operating one by one.
- Other modules.

```
// define states of the instance
    enum class State {
        A,
        B,
        C,
        ....
    };

// handle input message, all the message passed to the Processor queue should be redirect to this function.
    void onInput(std::shared_ptr<Message> msg) {
        switch(msg->mgsId) {
        case 1: 
             // do something
        break;
        case 2: 
             // do something
        break; 
        default: 
        break; 
        }
    }

....
```

The thing is, the Processor Class getting bigger and bigger when the number of signals increases; and if I have to do something break the flow like waiting for a specific event before continue operating, the code becomes very hard to read.

I know it's a very newbie question. But I have no idea how to restructure my code in a readable way.

Comment: I'd write one class per signal type, create one class instance per concrete signal and have all of them keep a link to the single queue instance. If you give the classes one common base class, you might even put all of them into a single `std::vector` (not by value, though, otherwise you run into object slicing).

Comment: @Aconcagua I think I got you point. But what if I want to check the current state of my Processor instance?
For example: if I in state A and received signal 1, I should do differently if I in state B and also receive signal 1.

Comment: @Aconcagua and eventually, I was added a lot of states to my instance too.

Comment: Just use the state you are in when you read the signal from queue. Signals usually can come in at arbitrary points of time and there's usually no need to distinguish between a signal arriving in state A while yet processing another one that provokes state change or the signal arriving right after that state change. Anything else quickly gets impracticable anyway (or would you want to roll back state changes? You'd have to store timestamps and keep state history then – and what if two different signals require contradicting state changes???).

Comment: @Aconcagua oh I think I got it now. I will create an class for each signal and make it a friend class of the processor class. The signals class instance will update the state of the Processor class and it's internal variable as well. Does it's sound right?

Comment: No. The singal handlers do not seem to be related closely enough to the processor so that they should be allowed to modify internal states directly. If this is necessary, provide the processor with some public API allowing to do so in a *controlled* manner. Still the question remains: Why at all? Why is switching states inside the processor while processing the signals from queue (which decouples signal handlers and processor entirely) not OK?

Comment: Side note: *If* some signals are more important than others and need to be processed more quickly, maybe a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) is what you should look at.

Comment: @Aconcagua The reason I have to update the state is because the Processor action is depend on the History of the Event. It's like the processor was received event 1,1,3,  should behave different than event 1, 2,3.

Comment: @Aconcagua It's similar to a FSM, I think.

Comment: But the history manifests within the queue itself: If signal 1 fires twice then signal 3, you get in the queue events in this order and will process them in right the same order. Now if signal 1 in state A triggers transition to state B, then do so while processing. When fetching the second event of type 1, you *are* already in state B and might transition to state C. If you find event of type 2 instead from second example, you might transition to D instead, so your FSM behaves differently already.

Comment: If you change state right when a signal comes in, then if signals 1, 1, 3 come in fast enough you might transition from A to B and right from B to C while first 1-event even hasn't started being processed, so you'd process it already in state C (or even E if event 3 transitions to there). Is there any reason you might need such behaviour?

Comment: Side note: You might avoid this whole queue hassle in a single threaded environment; your processor might allow to register signal handlers, these would provide a getter for a file descriptor and you could [`poll`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or [`select`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) on these (`HANDLE` and [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects) on Windows). Whenever a file descriptor fires you might process the event directly, without queue.

Comment: @Aconcagua It's clear now. I'll go ahead with you suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following answer (which I took from a comment by [Aconcagua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1312382/aconcagua)):

> I'd write one class per signal type, create one class instance per
> concrete signal and have all of them keep a link to the single queue
> instance. If you give the classes one common base class, you might
> even put all of them into a single `std::vector` (not by value, though,
> otherwise you run into object slicing). – Aconcagua